# Laravel: Check in controller if field has value before passing onto `view`

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have two table, one is `User` that stores login credentials and other is `Userinfo` that deals with storing personal information about the users. When a user sign up, they do not require filling up all the inputs for `UserInfo` table (i.e. they might only fill up the `Gender` and `Religion` fields out of a few other). So, the end result is that the `UserInfo` ends up being filled with only a couple of values or none at all.

The issue I am facing right now is when I pass through the data from both tables to view, and display them in typical laravel way, it throws an error `Trying to get property of non-object`. This is expected since not all the users have complete data from `UserInfo` table. I tried many methods both in controller and view to deal with the error message but failed to find a solution.

Is there a way to check the columns for empty or half complete value and deal with them properly in controller before passing onto the view? I think these checks should be performed in the controller or anywhere other than in the view. If there are none, how do I deal with them in the view? Maybe inside the loop? Solution and suggestions are greatly appreciated! Here's my code in the view:

```
@forelse($donors as $donor)

    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> {{$donor->name}}</div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                    <div class="basic-info">

                        <h4>Basic Information</h4>

                        <p><strong>Blood Group: </strong>{{  $donor->user_info->blood  }}</p>
                        <p><strong>Sex: </strong>{{ $donor->user_info->sex }}</p>
                        <p><strong>Religion: </strong>{{ $donor->user_info->religion }}</p>
                        <p><strong>Age: </strong>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($donor->user_info->dob)->age }}</p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


@empty

    <p>No records found!</p>

@endforelse
```

As you can see, because not all the user have complete data in the table, laravel throws the `Trying to get property of non-object` error. My controller has standard laravel method of passing data to views:

```
public function index(User $user, Request $request)
{

    $donors = $user->with('user_info')->latest()->paginate(5);

    return view('donors.index', compact('donors'));
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to do the check in your view. If there is a value, then display it. I believe in Blade you can use `or`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 5.5, Laravel has an [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper that I think it can help you.

Try something like this in your view:

```
optional($donor->user_info)->blood
```

Comment: That was quick! Not sure if that will help others, but that solved the problem.